# Is there a way to force mdset table exports to use value labels instead of variable labels?

Tags: expss

I am working from an exported SPSS file. Currently when I export a table that uses mdset, it picks up the respective variable labels to use as rows in the exported excel tables. The problem is that the SPSS variable labels are all formatted as "Full question text - answer option", which when exported is a bit messy.

Looking at the SPSS, the value labels in each column however are nicely coded as 1 = answer option, so was wondering if there is way to keep the variable labels so that we have a record of the question text, but only use the value labels when it comes to tabulating the rows for the multi response question?